# python rewrite the init

Tags: python, constructor, init

I want to be able to be able to run a function from my model "ModelLog" in the following way:

```
ModelLog.create_log(user, obj1, obj2)
```

instead of creating first and empty object to pass along with it.
Now i figured out this could be done by rewriting the **init** But to be fair, this is all new to me.

my class ModelLog has this method:

```
class ModelLog(models.Model):

    def create_log(user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
        """ Create a log about the changes of an object"""

        "Some Code"
```

When i use ModelLog.create_log(user, obj1, obj2)  to execute my create_log method i get the following error:

TypeError: unbound method create_log() must be called with ModelLog instance as first argument (got User instance instead)

now i thought i needed to do something like:

```
def __init__(self, user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
    self.user_obj = user_obj
    self.old_obj = old_obj
    self.new_obj = new_obj
```

But clearly, this isnt working,  can someone please put me in the right direction and help me out here?

Comment: I literally trying to understand your intention for 5 mins. But I can't say I got it.

Comment: Does your ModelLog inherit from any class?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explination, as said i dont really get how the init works. .  and I guess it does,  im using the djangoframework, so my model is   class ModelLog(models.Model):

Comment: Is your `ModelLog` a class or just a module (a bunch of methods)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5fXYteFB  My full django model

Comment: You are calling another constructor of that class in the `create_log` method... maybe the problem is that `create_log` just should not be a method of the class. Try to move it to module level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are calling a method like a class method. When you define a method in python you need to add an extra parameter which represent the object instance for the calling or (like your case) the class.

So you should rewrite your code:

```
def create_log(cls, user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
    """ Create a log about the changes of an object"""
```

Or in a more pythonic way:

```
@classmethod
def create_log(cls, user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
    """ Create a log about the changes of an object"""
```

Or in case you want a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def create_log(user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
    """ Create a log about the changes of an object"""
```

If you are interested(confused) I recommend you to read [this](http://www.pythoncentral.io/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python/).

Comment: Yes this work,  now lets learn a bit more about what im actualy doing here.  my mind seems to have problems understanding this part at the moment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call create_log as a static method (one that isn't linked to a single object) you'll need to use the [static method decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Try doing something like

```
class ModelLog(models.Model):

    @staticmethod
    def create_log(user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
        """ Create a log about the changes of an object"""

        pass #Create your object here
```

You probably don't need to customise your `__init__` method for this usecase, just forget about that for now.

Comment: Thanks this seem to work, now i am gonne google a bit more about what i am actualy doing

Answer (score 0):

As for your error, you need to provide a dummy first argument to `create_log` and declare it a `@classmethod`:

```
class ModelLog:

  @classmethod
  def create_log(self, user_obj, old_obj, new_obj):
    ...
```

Note the extra `self`.